# Results of jQuery $("#id").html() not Visible During Document Ready Function?

Tags: jquery, progress

I'm making a quick javascript progress function named showLoadProgress(). It is called repeatedly from within the buildMyPage() function seen in the sample code, until the function is complete.

If I'm running the debugger, at breakpoints I can see that the contents of the "#loadingMessage" element are being updated as expected.

But when the debugger isn't running, I don't see the changes to the contents of the "#loadingMessage" element.  The content remains static.

How can I correct this?

Thanks in advance to all for any info.

```
function showLoadProgress(currentActionDuringLoad, totalActionsForLoad)
{
    var percent = Math.round((currentActionDuringLoad / totalActionsForLoad) * 100);
    var percentString = percent + "%";
    $("#loadingMessage").html(percentString);
}

$(document).ready(function()
{ 
    buildMyPage();
});
```

Comment: Are you getting an error in the console without the debugger, or is just nothing happening at all?

Comment: you supplied partial code, what does buildMyPage do?

Comment: Maybe you're just looping and looping in JavaScript, giving no chance for browser to update view.

Comment: @Haocheng, I think that's what's happening. How do progress bars get around this so that they can update while a javascript task is running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand, you're trying to update the DOM `$("#loadingMessage").html()` against rapid speeds your browser may not be able to follow. There is something called reflow which your browser does everytime the page gets altered or resized. Rendering the changes so to speak.

In order for you to generate reflow each time your function is complete, you will have to wrap this function in a `$.Deferred` object or webworker as stated in the comments or create your own custom callbacks.
When a job is done these functions will generate callbacks for you to pick up and show your progress.

A nice wrapper of $.Deferred objects can be found in jQuery `.animate()` or `$.ajax()`.
Since I don't know how you will verify your loadingProgress at each step I've combined `.animate()` with a `.progressbar()` widget and a custom callback you can modify later on.

To fake your behaviour jQuery's $.Deferred wrappers, for page load e.g. document.ready and window.load, are perfect. In between this timeframe I can load a progressbar and generate reflow with `.animate()`. I'll display the basics here and create a jsfiddle to see it in action. I can think of an array filled with URL's to load external scripts with ajax for example.

In short, executing the following:

```
// once the dom is ready
$(function () {
    bar = $(".progressbar");
    buildMyProgressbar.init();
    buildMyPage.init();
});

// once the page is loaded
$(window).load(function () {
    buildMyProgressbar.stop();
});
```

When the progressbar is intialized work through your amount of progresses with `.animate()`. I'll pass in a `pageload` which is nothing more than the numeric id of one progress step or as I called it "job" and the amount of "jobs".

```
animation: function (pageload) {
    $({
        job: pageload.fakeJob // starts at 1
    }).animate({
        job: pageload.fakeJobs // end at jobs.length
    }, {
        duration: 1000,
        step: function () {
            var percent = Math.round((this.job / pageload.fakeJobs) * 100),
                percentString = percent + "%";

            // verify your job is loaded
            if (buildMyPage.isJobLoaded(this.job)){
                bar.children().eq(0).css({ width: percent + "%" }).text("loading: " + percent);
            }
        },
        complete: function(){
            bar.children().eq(0).text("complete");
        }
    });
}
```

jQuery UI Progressbar: http://jqueryui.com/progressbar/

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/tive/b2Utn/

Comment: Tim, thanks so much for this extremely educational post. I am studying it and learning a great deal. As I study it I may have a question or two.

I don't yet recognize what this is:

                bar.progressbar();

I don't see a function progressbar() defined in the code, and it doesn't appear to be part of the jQuery API. Where is progressbar() defined?

Comment: Ah yes, it's jQuery UI. I've checked this in fiddle to load as well.

Comment: Tim, a follow-up question if I may. My current buildMyPage() contains one ajax call followed by a number of loops which use the data returned by the ajax call, and which take a few seconds to execute. Do I drop this code (ajax call and all) into buildMyPage.init, and call buildMyProgressbar.animation() repeatedly as the loops are running? Thanks in advance for the info.

Comment: That way you will initiate the progressbar for every step in the for loop. Perhaps you can try to change `buildMyPage.isJobLoaded(your id here)` if you only want one progress indicator. My answer is a little bit flawed with the `this.job` since the animation will not necessarily step on each iteration.

Comment: Very good. I can modify buildMyPage.isJobLoaded so that it exits and is called again repeatedly until the job is complete. Just for my info, why does it not work to call buildMyProgressbar.animation repeatedly from inside buildMyPage.isJobLoaded?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setTimeout()` instead of simple loop, giving chance for browser to update view.

From

```
while (...) {
    // do something
}
```

to

```
var doSomething = function() {
    // do something
    setTimeout(doSomething, 10); 
};
doSomething();
```

Furthermore, WebWorkers can be used if it would take long time to execute.